# Render view another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have a noob problem. I need render view from another controller. I use devise and create a perfil controller.

Perfil Controller:

```
class PerfilController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    def index
    end

    def show

        @usuario = User.find(current_user)
        @usuario.perfil ||= @usuario.build_perfil
        @perfil = @usuario.perfil
    end

    def update
     @usuario = User.find(current_user)
     @perfil = Perfil.new(perfil_params)
     @usuario.perfil ||= @usuario.build_perfil

     respond_to do |format|

          if @usuario.perfil.update_attributes(perfil_params)
          format.html {redirect_to @usuario, notice: "update" }
     else
        format.html { render action: "show"}
     end
  end
 end

  private

    def perfil_params
       params.require(:perfil).permit(:nombre, :apellido)
    end
 end
```

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def index
    @users = User.all
    authorize User
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize user
    user.destroy
     redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end


  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

end

class PerfilController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    def index
    end

    def show

         @usuario = User.find(current_user)
         @usuario.perfil ||= @usuario.build_perfil
         @perfil = @usuario.perfil 
    end

      def update
       @usuario = User.find(current_user)
       @perfil = Perfil.new(perfil_params)
       @usuario.perfil ||= @usuario.build_perfil

       respond_to do |format|

            if @usuario.perfil.update_attributes(perfil_params)
             format.html {redirect_to @usuario, notice: "actualizado" }
            else
             format.html { render action: "show"}
            end
   end
end

  private

    def perfil_params
      params.require(:perfil).permit(:nombre, :apellido)
    end
 end
```

Perfil/show

```
<h2>Edit </h2>

<%= form_for @perfil, :url=>{:action=>:update}, :html=>{:method=>:put} do |f| %>


<p><%= f.label :nombres %><br />
<%= f.text_field :nombre %></p>

  <div><%= f.label :apellidos %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :apellido %></div>



  <div><%= f.submit "Actualizar" %></div>
<% end %>


<%= link_to "Atrás", :back %>
```

well, i need show update in users/index

```
<h3>Configuracion de la cuenta</h3>
<div class = "col-md-3">   <h3>Users</h3>
<div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<%= render 'users/menu' %>
</div>
</div>
<div class = "col-md-7">   
<h3>Informacion</h3>
 <%= render 'users/show' %>
</div>
```

I hope I explained well.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can render any view from your application..using [render](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render)
take care of the variables used inside the view and do include them in the method call.

**RENDER ONLY RENDERS THE VIEW AND DO NOT CALLS THE ACTION OF THE CONTROLLER**

render other controller view from the controller..

in users_controller.rb

```
##render partial from views/profile
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js { render 'profile/upload' }
       format.html 'profile/upload'
    end
```

same can be used in view file as well

```
<%= render 'profile/upload'%>
```

Comment: Sorry ajaja.. I dont Understand!! :/